# Push & Pop Problems Programmatically Created UINavigationController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I have a view controller (MailServicesController) which I have presented modally. I am trying to add to this MailServicesController a UINavigationController (programmatically) that will allow me to push and pop another view controller (LoginController).  I have implemented code to do this but am having two specific problems:

1. The navigation controller pushes the loginViewController onto the top of the stack, but does not animate this transition even though I have set the animation BOOL to YES in the push method.
2. Once in the loginViewController, when I try to use popViewControllerAnimated, nothing happens (I made my own button for popping, I am not using the nav controller's navbar).

Here is the code I use to create the nav controller inside the MailServices modal view controller:

```
self.navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc]init];
[self.navigationController willMoveToParentViewController:self];
self.navigationController.view.frame = self.view.frame;
[self.view addSubview:self.navigationController.view];
[self addChildViewController:self.navigationController];
[self.navigationController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:LoginController animated:YES];
//pushes login controller but with no animation
```

Then in the LoginController, I try to pop the LoginController off the top to reveal the controller I pushed from:

```
- (void)dismissView //called by a button in my custom toolbar
{

  UINavigationController *navigationController = (UINavigationController   
  *)self.parentViewController; //this is the navigationController I created
  [navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES]; //is called but does nothing
}
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong, can anyone see my mistake?

Comment: where you initialize the UINavigation Controller either else where

Comment: i only initialize it in above code

Comment: you want navigation throughout the app or this two classes alone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While presenting modally to MailServicesController do like this

```
MailServicesController *vc = [[MailServicesController alloc]init];
UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:vc];
[self presentModalViewController:navController animated:YES];
```

After that present your MailServicesController, now it have all properties of UINavigationController

In MailServicesController while pushing loginViewController just use

```
LoginViewController *vc = [[LoginViewController alloc]init];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
```

While pop up LoginViewController

```
- (void)dismissView //called by a button in my custom toolbar
{

    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES]; //is called but does nothing
}
```

Comment: Thanks, after I init the nav controller with MailServicesController as the root, if I then try to modally present MailServicesController, it crashes.

Comment: Check my updated answer. It should work. And please remove your code which you used to create UINavigationController inside of MailServicesController